# Why am I getting an error when trying to append values to dictionary key?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, append

I am working on creating a dictionary from two lists, and the resulting dictionary will include some keys that have more than one value.

The two lists are `jpg_paths` and `jpg_ID`. I am iterating through the lists to match up the values with the keys, but am having trouble appending values if the key already exists.

When I try to append, I get an error `'str' object has no attribute 'append'`. How can I append values?

```
for j in jpg_ID:
    for jp in jpg_paths:
        if j in jp:
            if j in pdf_dict.keys():
                pdf_dict[j].append(jp)
            else:
                pdf_dict[j] = jp
print pdf_dict
```

Comment: As the error message *tells you*, `pdf_dict[j]` is a string, which you can't append to. What exactly is confusing you?

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit this question so it is not off topic. I included my code example. I guess the error message I got was obvious in terms of what the issue was but at the time I didn't think to just set my value to be a list. Sometimes it is hard to take a step back and see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your first value to be a string:

```
pdf_dict[j] = jp
```

If you wanted a list value instead (*containing* strings) then use one:

```
pdf_dict[j] = [jp]
```

That's a list with a single (string) element.

Some other notes:

- There is no need to call `.keys()` when testing for membership. Do so against the dictionary directly:

  ```
  if j in pdf_dict:
  ```
- You can use the [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to set the value to an empty list if the key is missing, that way you only ever need to use `.append()` and you don't need to test whether the key already exists:

  ```
  pdf_dict.setdefault(j, []).append(jp)
  ```
- You can build the list in one go instead, using a list comprehension:

  ```
  for j in jpg_ID:
      pdf_dict[j] = [jp for jp in jpg_paths if j in jp]
  ```

  This can be replaced by a dict comprehension

  ```
  pdf_dict = {j: [jp for jp in jpg_paths if j in jp] for j in jpg_ID]}
  ```

Comment: @holdenweb: I thought that is what the part *set to an empty list if the key is missing* was meant to imply.